# A coworker has abandoned mountain biking for Moro-cross. He gave me the option to buy this bike. I am not sure it’s value

Tags: price, fox

Specialized FSR Camber

WSBC601
096687M
BI 2542
8 SEM
Size Medium

Comment: From which year is it? In which condition is it? Is it the right size for you? How much would a new one cost?

Answer (score 1):

Straight up - bike valuations are off topic because they're of short term use to one person in one place, and do not form part of the long-term useful body of knowledge that SE is trying to build.  This is an attempt at an agnostic answer.

**Value** is colloquially defined as the equivalent trade for an item or service.  So between the seller and buyer, if they can come to a mutually agreeable monetary value, then that's its value.

For a common item like a cup of dirt, the value is low because there's a lot of it, its not rare.   For a one-off artwork the value is high because there are no others ever and never will be.   A bicycle is somewhere in the middle.

Considerations that **raise** the value:

- Availability - if bikes are hard to get in your area at this time, that drives up prices somewhat.
- Uniqueness - Some bikes just look cool.  Others just look weird (like softrides)  Either way being strange can increase the price.
- Sizing - As a tall rider, big bikes are rare and hard to find.  I've spent more on a big bike purely because it was my size.  Same goes for quality small-adults bikes (as opposed to kids bikes), and bikes rated for high load (large-people bikes)
- Spares - if the seller changed something, are spare parts or takeoff parts included?  This applies more on conversions like singlespeed/fixie or flatbar, where the removed parts have value in their own right, like downtube shifters where someone has converted to STI levers.
- Warranty and Documentation - some bikes have a couple of years warranty from new.  Some have "lifetime" frame warranty, maybe for the original owner.  Having a folder of paperwork is a positive sign.  Whether the warranty is transferable is a separate point.

Considerations that **affect** the value:

- Overall condition and wear - a worn drivetrain or tyres need replacing sooner, you're not buying as much "remaining lifetime"  Recently replaced parts might be equal, higher, or lower grade parts, but a new unworn lower part is arguably better than an higher-quality worn-out part.
- Originality vs Upgrades - can be a mixed bag.  A vintage road bike that should have downtube shifters may have been upgraded to STI Brifters for convenience, but that's a loss of originality.  Depends if the replacement is more attractive than the originality.   Likewise, a MTB that had hydraulic brakes, now wearing cable brakes may be perceived as an upgrade or a downgrade.

Considerations that **lower** the value:

- Brand - there are some brands that are known rubbish because they are sold by big-box stores like Walmart or similar.  Modern Milazo, Dunlop, Huffey, etc are all low-cost/low-value brands.
- Provenance - if the seller is sketchy and there's no paperwork, and they don't know anything about it, the bike is not their size, then there's a great chance its stolen and you should politely pass this up.  Receiving stolen goods is a crime in many parts of the world.
- Incompleteness - Lack of a critical part like a wheel, saddle, etc.  You have to go find a substitute before the bike is usable.
- Condition - rust, lack of lube, crusted with dirt, frame damage, non-functional gears/brakes, leaks of fluid, punctures, non-true wheels, gummy grips, tears in the saddle, etc will all subtract.  Sure, some of these items are easily fixed, but they contribute to value.

Ultimately its between you and the seller to agree.  Sometimes the seller just wants to see the bike go somewhere it will be used and not cluttering up space in their garage.  Other times the seller has a new pit for tipping money, and hopes for as much as possible to fund the new hobby.

Selling to someone you know can be good or bad, its more convenient than listing an auction or visiting a bike buyer/trader, but limits the selection of buyers.  If there are significant problems later (find a cracked frame) then that can sour the working relationship.    Caveat emptor only goes so far.

---